# How can I obtain percentage frequencies in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get percentage frequencies in pyspark. I did this in python as follows

```
Companies = df['Company'].value_counts(normalize = True)
```

Getting the frequencies is fairly straightforward:

```
# Dates in descending order of complaint frequency 
df.createOrReplaceTempView('Comp')
CompDF = spark.sql("SELECT Company, count(*) as cnt \
                    FROM Comp \
                    GROUP BY Company \
                    ORDER BY cnt DESC")
CompDF.show()
```

```
+--------------------+----+  
|             Company| cnt|  
+--------------------+----+  
|BANK OF AMERICA, ...|1387|  
|       EQUIFAX, INC.|1285|  
|WELLS FARGO & COM...|1119|  
|Experian Informat...|1115|  
|TRANSUNION INTERM...|1001|  
|JPMORGAN CHASE & CO.| 905|  
|      CITIBANK, N.A.| 772|  
|OCWEN LOAN SERVIC...| 481|
```

How do I get to percent frequencies from here? I tried a bunch of things with not much luck. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about using total count to calculate percentage.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Suresh implies in the comments, assuming that `total_count` is the number of rows in dataframe `Companies`, you can use `withColumn` to add a new column named `percentages` in `CompDF`:

```
total_count = Companies.count()

df = CompDF.withColumn('percentage', CompDF.cnt/float(total_counts))
```

Comment: This looks very clean and straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be modifying the SQL query will get you the result you want.

```
    "SELECT Company,cnt/(SELECT SUM(cnt) from (SELECT Company, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM Comp GROUP BY Company ORDER BY cnt DESC) temp_tab) sum_freq from 
    (SELECT Company, count(*) as cnt FROM Comp GROUP BY Company ORDER BY cnt 
    DESC)"
```